# Magento: Using a product chooser widget when creating a custom form in the admin panel

Tags: magento, admin, product

I am developing a Magento (1.7.0.2) module that has its own management area in the admin panel.

This area contains a form to update some settings which includes a text field to enter a product ID. Instead of this text field I would like to use a product chooser widget because checking for the right product ID and then manually entering the found ID in the form is a pain in the a**.

Currently the code for the mentioned text field looks like the following:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'product_id', 
    'text', 
    array(
        'label'     => $helper->__('Product'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'product_id'
    )
);
```

Is there an easy way to display a product chooser widget instead of the textfield?

Comment: @Subsruf, Have you read the post here? http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/magento-product-selector.html

Answer (score 2):

This approach might be an option:
http://andreitara.com/2012/02/using-magento-product-chooser-widget-in-youre-own-module/

Comment: I also came across that idea, but I thought it was such a dirty solution. I was hoping for something easy, like just changing the field's type to "product_chooser" or whatever. Anyway, I guess as always in Magento, it is just not that easy. I will have to go that way at least until I (or someone else) has found a better one.

Comment: @Subsurf Yes, the solution does not seem to be very convenient, I agree. Share here, if you come across a better alternative!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I'm going to put this here for people still having this problem.

I'd suggest trying this module: [Extendix_AdminFormChooserButton](http://ceckoslab.com/magento/extension-admin-form-chooser-selector-button/). It's [GitHub is here](https://github.com/extendix/Extendix_AdminFormChooserButton).  It's a bit more than changing the field type to "product_chooser" but it's way easier than any other solution I've come across so far.

It had trouble automatically setting my value after I saved it and would load empty when the page loaded.  To fix this you can edit Extendix/AdminFormChooserButton/Helper/Chooser.php and add

```
if (isset($config['value'])){
    $element->setValue($config['value']);
}
```

after

```
$element->setValue($dataModel->getData($element->getId()));
```

and then you should be able to define your own 'value' in the config definition

It should be noted that this module doesn't support selecting multiple products for one field. If you want more than one product you'll need multiple fields.

Comment: This isn't a very constructive solution as it is just suggesting purchasing an extension rather than explaining functionally how to accomplish this. Furthermore, this comment encourages directly modifying the third party extension code which is also frowned upon. If modifying a module's code it needed the best practice way is to create a new module depending on the first and using dependency injection to override whichever function is needed (see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html).